# localStorage["itemName"] vs. localStorage.getItem("itemName");

Tags: javascript

Just wondwering, what is the correct cross browser use of localStorage. I have seen both, accessing localStorage through attributes as well as through getItem() and both seem to work. So what is better/correct?

```
localStorage["itemName"]

// or

localStorage.getItem("itemName");
```